# How can I pass an empty string into triple quoted f-string in Python?

Tags: python, lxml, string-literals, f-string

Here is a function using a triple quoted f-string with lots of sub-elements:

```
def pass_empty_string(param):
    from lxml import etree
    xml = etree.XML(f'''
    <root>
        <child>text</child>
        <child>{param}</child>
        ...
    </root>''')
    return xml
```

Is it possible to get an empty `</child>` element when `param` is getting `None` or `''` value?

Comment: have you tried this? If you pass `''` then a child is empty but passing `None` has `<child>None</child>`; the other elements are present if you just want an empty child element see answer below

Comment: sorry, tried `''` only with if-else statement and got `<child>''</child>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish this with `or`:

```
f"<child>{param or ''}</child>"
```

Anything in the braces is evaluated as an expression, so...

```
>>> param = None
>>> f"<child>{param or ''}</child>"
'<child></child>'
>>> param = ''
>>> f"<child>{param or ''}</child>"
'<child></child>'
>>> param = "some valid child"
>>> f"<child>{param or ''}</child>"
'<child>some valid child</child>'
```

Both `''` and `None` are falsy values, so it will fall back to the RHS of the `or`, which will be just an empty string.

Comment: Didn't know you could do this!

Comment: @Farhan.K Anything in the `{}` is evaluated as an expression -- this is the power of f-strings.

Comment: Very cool.  You can even execute ternary conditions like `f"<child>{param1 if param1 else param2}</child>"` within the braces.  Learned something new, thanks!

Comment: @Idlehands You could even have another `f`-string within the `{...}` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just use `if` statements?

```
def pass_empty_string(param):
    from lxml import etree
    if param is None or param == '':
        return etree.XML(f'<child></child>')
    xml = etree.XML(f'''
    <root>
        <child>text</child>
        <child>{param}</child>
        ...
    </root>''')
    return xml
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `if` statement will do:

```
def pass_empty_string(param):
    if not param:
        param = ''
    xml = etree.XML(f'''<root>
            <child>text</child>
            <child>{param}</child>
        </root>''')
    return xml
```

`xml` looks like this:

```
<root>
    <child>text</child>
    <child></child>
</root>
```